# delay with set color filter java

Tags: java, android

I have a loop which makes a sound and changes the background color of a button during each
increment. the sound works , but the background color using porterduff mode does not change until the loop is complete. I want each button color to change as the counter increments.

any ideas?
here is a snippet of my code:

```
for ( int i=1;i <= cupvalue; i++)   {
            if (soundvalue) { mSoundManager.playSound(1); }
            buttons[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); //red
            beadcount--;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay); // delay sounds for each drop
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The "Thread.sleep(delay) works, to slow down the sounds , but doesnt work for the setColorFilter, just updates all the buttons at the end of the loop.
thx

Answer (score 1):

**You should not perform blocking operations on the main thread**

You should run this code in a background thread, and perform only the UI modifications on main thread. You can achieve that with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html).

There's a great article that explains the reasons and usage called [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), which I recommend that you read.

Answer (score 0):

does the buttons[i] exist in the first place?, you could try to get first the layout (parent) then traverse thru it using getChildCount() and getChildAt() then applying the desired colored on the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to call `.invalidate()`on your views to warn the system that it need to be redrawn (see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) here)

```
...
buttons[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
buttons[i].invalidate()
...
```

And if you are looping in a background thread (as advised by MByD in his answer, and I surely agree) you could try calling `.postInvalidate()`instead (here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate())).